# Unresolved External Symbol with Qt private API

Tags: c++, qt

I wish to test some code against some private qt classes. (I'm well aware that this is not a public API and can change even in minor versions, and that this would break binary compatibility)

The only thing I did to access the private headers was adding QT += network-private in the .pro.

But It doesn't seem enough.

When I include

```
#include <QtNetwork/private/qnetworkreplyhttpimpl_p.h>
```

and I try to instantiate a QNetworkReplyHttpImpl object I receive the following unresolved external symbol

> ssonetworkmanager.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "public: __cdecl QNetworkReplyHttpImpl::QNetworkReplyHttpImpl(class
>   QNetworkAccessManager * const,class QNetworkRequest const &,enum
>   QNetworkAccessManager::Operation &,class QIODevice *)"
>   (??0QNetworkReplyHttpImpl@@QEAA@QEAVQNetworkAccessManager@@AEBVQNetworkRequest@@AEAW4Operation@1@PEAVQIODevice@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: class QNetworkReply * __cdecl
>   SsoNetworkManager::get(class QNetworkRequest const &)"
>   (?get@SsoNetworkManager@@QEAAPEAVQNetworkReply@@AEBVQNetworkRequest@@@Z)

Does someone know how to compile something that relies on the private API? Am I missing something apart from the QT += *whatever*-private in the .pro file?

Comment: I recently had similar problems, might be related: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62948

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently don't have the Qt source in front of me, so this is more of a "wild guess" than a real answer.

Under windows in order to be visible in a compiled .dll, a symbol needs to be marked with `__declspec(dllexport)` in the library and `__declspec(dllimport)` in the using project. If thats not the case, the linker can not find the symbol because either it was never exported or it just doesn`t know that it should be looking in a library (depending on which one is missing).

For Linux, exporting is default, but there are ways to mark symbols as private.

Depending on your OS/compiler and the Qt sources, either you would have to modify the headers (add import/export or remove private) or you also need to compile the source files in your project (and of course all headers/source files they rely on).
There might also be a compiler flag for "export by default" (Win) or "ignore private" (Linux), but you would have to look in the documentation of your compiler for that.

Comment: thank you for the answer, actually I am using QT on Windows. So to recap: QT += *whatever*-private is used just to access the private headers. The symbols (both from the public and private APIs) are contained in the general module DLLs, specifically in this case, in the Qt5Network.dll. But to see the private ones probably I need to recompile the DLL using __declspec().I will try and let you know if everything works!

Comment: That would be my guess. If Qt offers an easy way to access the headers, i would also expect an easy way to set the __declspec() for all private classes, maybe with some sort of macro definition?

Comment: That is indeed the case. See https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.9/src/network/access/qnetworkreplyhttpimpl_p.h#L81. Neither the class nor it's methods are exported, thus it will not work on windows.